# Name of the numeric sets defined by the number of digits in a whole number

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for each set of whole (or the number before the decimal) numbers by their digit count? I know place value has names: ones, tens, hundreds, etc, but what do you call the sets { 0 ... 9 }, { 10 ... 99 }, { 100 ... 999 }, etc?

Comment: You can call them the set of one digit numbers, two digit numbers and so on...

Comment: Thank you. l want to refer to the transition from one set of n-digit integers to n+1-digit integers (or from any set to any other set) in a general way. I was thinking there would be a similar term like logarithmic scale 'decades' https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decade_(log_scale)

Comment: I don't know of a standard name for this. If you need a name, then I think you could reasonably use "decade" provided you explain exactly how you are using that term.